# Como ter uma opção que saia do programa ou continue executando com as outras?

Tags: c

Tem como adicionar uma terceira opção ao perguntar ao usuário, sendo que está opção só vai aparecer após o primeiro cálculo. Ex. (3 sair). Eu só pensei na forma  que surgem as 3 opções desde o início.

```
#include <stdio.h>

  int soma(void)
  {
      int valor, soma;
      soma = 0;
      printf("Foi escolhida a soma:\n\n");
      do
      {
          printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
          scanf("%d", &valor);
          soma += valor;
      }
      while(valor!=0);

      return soma;
  }

  int mult(void)
  {
      int valor, mult;
      mult= 1;
      printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
      do{
           printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
           scanf("%d", &valor);
           if(valor==0)
           {
                break;
           }
           mult*= valor;
      }
      while(valor!=0);

      return mult;
  }

  int main()
  {
      int op ,result;
      printf("Informe a operacao desejada soma(1) ou produto (2):");
      scanf("%d", &op);

      if(op==1)
      {
          result = soma();
      }  
      else if(op==2)
      {
          result = mult();
      }

      printf("O resultado foi: %d", result);
      return 0;

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só acrescentar um laço no `main()`. Eu preferi usar o 0 para sair para manter a consistência:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma(void) {
    int valor = 0, soma = 0;
    printf("Foi escolhida a soma:\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        soma += valor;
    } while (valor != 0);
    return soma;
}

int mult(void) {
    int valor = 0, mult = 1;
    printf("Foi escolhida a multiplicacao:\n\n");
    do {
        printf("Informe os valores desejados e 0 (zero) para concluir:");
        scanf("%d", &valor);
        if (valor == 0) break;
        mult *= valor;
    } while (valor != 0);
    return mult;
}

int main() {
    int op = 0, result;
    do {
        printf("Informe a operacao desejada soma(1) ou produto (2):");
        scanf("%d", &op);
        if (op == 1) result = soma();
        else if (op == 2) result = mult();
        if (op != 0) printf("O resultado foi: %d", result);
    } while (op != 0);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WCkGO3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zyyavozy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/ExitLoop.c).

Comment: Muito obrigado!